# Zookeeper: java.io.IOException: No snapshot found, but there are log entries. Something is broken

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I have been working with [Kafka 2.4.0](https://www.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.4.0/RELEASE_NOTES.html) (2.11) and yesterday I had to forcefully terminate the process for some unknown reason. Since then I haven't been unable to start Zookeeper due to the following error:

```
[2020-01-11 11:12:43,783] ERROR Unexpected exception, exiting abnormally (org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain)
java.io.IOException: No snapshot found, but there are log entries. Something is broken!
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.persistence.FileTxnSnapLog.restore(FileTxnSnapLog.java:222)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZKDatabase.loadDataBase(ZKDatabase.java:240)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.loadData(ZooKeeperServer.java:290)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer.startdata(ZooKeeperServer.java:450)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.startup(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:764)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxnFactory.startup(ServerCnxnFactory.java:98)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.runFromConfig(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:144)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.initializeAndRun(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:106)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServerMain.main(ZooKeeperServerMain.java:64)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.initializeAndRun(QuorumPeerMain.java:128)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain.main(QuorumPeerMain.java:82)
```

And as soon as I searched for this problem I found issue [ZOOKEEPER-3513](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3513) reported, which may or may not explain the problem. However, what I'm finding strange is that if I delete the Kafka/Zookeeper directory and download it again from scratch, the problem persists. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: You shouldn't need to re-download anything. There's no state stored outside of those data directories

Comment: what about the directory /tmp/zookeeper ?

Comment: Isn't that the dataDir? Besides, you should not store data on /tmp anyway

Comment: have you tried the workaround with `snapshot.0` file described in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3056?

Answer (score 86):

Check for the **tmp/zookeeper** folder on the drive where you have kafka folder (lets say D:/), and delete the folder tmp, which will create automatically for you once run the zookeeper again.

Comment: this works for me, in Linux I used: rm -rf /tmp/zookeeper/*

Comment: I also had to delete broker files for this to work.
deleted broker files from /tmp folder.

Answer (score 13):

---

On **windows** ->

Go to the tmp folder where the zookeeper details are stored
and delete the existing log files

Directory path = **d:\tmp\zookeeper\version-2**

---

On **Linux** ->

Path =  **/tmp/zookeeper/version-2**

And remove all the existing log files using **rm -r log.1**

The log files will be created automatically again and will resolve the issue.

---

Comment: Linux location was the same for mac OS

Answer (score 10):

Try changing your zookeeper data directory.
Your zookeeper data directory is defined in zookeeper.properties (I think the default is /tmp/zookeeper).

Perhaps you're not deleting the correct zookeeper directory?

I had the same problem, and this solution worked.

NOTE: I'm experimenting with Kafka, and not using it in production. I have no idea what else the above does, apart from fix this error...

Answer (score 6):

I've faced the same issue with Zookeeper after updating from version 3.4.x to 3.5.6. As described [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3056). I've:

1. added empty snapshot.0 file in data directory
2. added a property 'zookeeper.snapshot.trust.empty=true' to Zookeeper configuration file (default is zoo.cfg)

Comment: For me, it didn't work with empty `snapshot.0`, but with the one attached at the link that you posted. +1 though, that's the workaround.

Comment: Download `sanpshot.0` from the given link and paste it to dataDir. Now, the question is where exactly the data directory exists?
I am using a mac and for me, the dataDir is located at `/usr/local/var/run/zookeeper/data/version-2`. You can check your dataDir inside zookeeper config file (zoo.cfg). Just add `version-x` to this dataDir.

Please read [this](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZOOKEEPER-3056?focusedCommentId=16519839&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-16519839) comment carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Faced same issue in macOS.
Solution: In kafka dir, path `cd /tmp/zookeeper/version-2` deleted the log.1 file. It worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this error. The above solution of deleting the zookeeper folder from tmp worked for me. For those who don't know how to find tmp folder on mac :
Open a Finder window. Click on "Go" in the menu bar at the top of the
screen. Select "Go to Folder" from the dropdown menu. In the dialog
box that appears, enter /tmp. Click the "Go" button.

This will open the /tmp directory where you can find the temporary files and folders. Then delete the zookeeper folder.

Answer (score 0):

if you are on windows make sure you escape the location of the zookeeper temp directory.

dataDir=d:\tmp\zookeeper

Comment: If you are not sure about any information to answer a question, you should ask them through comments.

Answer (score 0):

Created a new dir for logs and configured the same path in zoo.cfg.
It worked:)

Answer (score 0):

I use macOS and my solution was to delete everything in the `dataDir`, the default value should be `/usr/local/var/lib/zookeeper`.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using **docker**, I'll share my experience:

I've been running zookeeper confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1 as it follows:

```
 docker run \
    --network kafka-net --name=zookeeper \
    -e ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes \
    -e ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT=2181 \
    -v /tmp/zookeeper-data:/var/lib/zookeeper/data \
    -v /tmp/zookeeper-txn-logs:/var/lib/zookeeper/log \
    -p 2181:2182 confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.2.1
```

As expected, I can see a few files placed in `/tmp/zookeeper-txn-logs` and `/tmp/zookeeper-data` on host.  After cleaning up */tmp/zookeeper-data* and running again, I've got the error *No snapshot found, but there are log entries.*

In my case, I just had to purge the data on `/tmp/zookeeper-txn-logs`. For a dev/production environment, I'd recommend following the docs https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_amq/6.3/html/fabric_guide/ensemble-purgetxnlog

Answer (score 0):

on mac it helped me to restart the computer but first delete the tmp/zookeper files

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).